# Display of Columns From Database

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 text files each of which contains a list of 20 items.
A new column will be added per new day.

I'd like to display these items in a spreadsheet or spreadsheet type layout with each column adjacent to the next.

Spreadsheet output like:

```
10-28-09 10-29-09 10-30-09
data1    data2    data3
data1    data2    data3
data1    data2    data3
```

I'm thinking of arranging the data in a mysql database, and execute a query to simply the process, however I can't figure out how to do a few things.

I can arrange the data like this:
DB schema; fields: varchar (50)
Columns name = date: 10-30-09 ( mon - fri);

The query would be simple then: "SELECT * FROM table1"

The data needs to expand horizontally so a new column needs to be created by day.

If I was to arrange the data by date like this, I'm not sure what the query would be to get the output into dated columns:

```
id  name   date
1   data1  10-28-09
2   data1  10-28-09
3   data1  10-28-09
4   data2  10-29-09
5   data2  10-29-09
6   data2  10-29-09
7   data3  10-30-09
8   data3  10-30-09
9   data3  10-30-09
```

I was thinking of adding a sort column and increment it 1-20 for all rows per date, but then you would need to join on every date somehow, again the output would be:

```
10-28-09 10-29-09 10-30-09
data1    data2    data3
data1    data2    data3
data1    data2    data3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to arrange your data in database columns from the database, you should write a front end to arrange the data. You certainly shouldn't be modifying the table every day to add a column.

It's possible that what you really want to do is have 20 columns in your data and add a row each day. Then transposing the data is a relatively easy job for your front end, but it's unclear from your question why you are trying to do this.

Comment: Any suggestions on a possible query using the info at the bottom of my post? It seems I need some sort of subselect join and a loop for each date.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a hard limit of 4,096 columns: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html

That's not an ideal method of storing things.  Arranging the data by date is better:

1. It won't hit the column limit
2. It supports optional relations.  For instance, if you don't have `data1` for a given date - the record won't exist.

### `TABLE`

- `RECORD_DATE`, [while you've stated varchar, I recommend DATETIME]
- `RECORD_VALUE`, varchar(50)

Pivoting/transposing the data requires using a CASE expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.record_date = '10-28-09' THEN t.record_value ELSE NULL END AS '10-28-09',
       CASE WHEN t.record_date = '10-29-09' THEN t.record_value ELSE NULL END AS '10-29-09',
       CASE WHEN t.record_date = '10-30-09' THEN t.record_value ELSE NULL END AS '10-30-09'
  FROM TABLE t
```

Reference: [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)

You might've noticed that the columns are hard coded - you'd want to consider using [MySQL's Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) to dynamically create the statement.

If you find that you're missing dates, you'd want to consider creating a numbers table so you can artificially construct dates by adding the appropriate value to a given date.

Comment: Hey rexem, thanks for the info on prepared statements and case. It seems the case conditional applies more-so for missing values. I tried to execute this:
SELECT CASE WHEN t.date = '10-28-09' THEN t.name ELSE NULL END AS '10-28-09'
  FROM TABLE t

which returned null values for the 9 rows in the test above.

It seems mysql isn't best suited for the simple task i'm trying to accomplish. The dataset i'm working with will always be a strict set of 20 items and the only variable is the column name (date).

Comment: To make a database as RJ suggested seems awkward, To display data horizontally seems beyond what mysql was intended for. My original solution seems like the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Rexem, any advice?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658943/php-simulate-mysql-result-set

Answer (score 0):

You can try ur problem with **DYNAMIC PIVOTING**.

A sample is given here.

------------------**Initial Table Creation & Data Population**---------------

```
create table #tblpk (id int identity,groupid int)
insert into #tblpk 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 
    union all select 2 union all select 2 union all select 1
    union all select 3

create table #tblfk (id int, groupdate datetime, flag int)
insert into #tblfk 
    select 1,'01/02/2009',1 union all 
    select 1,'02/02/2009',0 union all 
    select 1,'03/02/2009',1
```

----------- **Program Starts** -------------------------------------------

-- Variable Declarations

```
declare @col_list varchar(max)

declare @dynquery varchar(max)
```

*--Step 1: Get all the matching records from the two tables*

```
select 
        tpk.id id
        ,tfk.groupdate groupdate
        ,tfk.flag 
into #allRectbl
from #tblpk tpk
inner join #tblfk tfk
on tpk.groupid = tfk.id
```

*--Step 2: Get the unique dynamic columns*

```
select distinct(Cols) as DynamicCols into #dynamicColumns from
(
    select      
        IsNull(@col_list,'') + 
        '[' + cast(groupdate as varchar(32)) + '],' as Cols
    from #allRectbl

)X(Cols)
```

*--Step 3: Make the dynamic pivot columns*

```
select @col_list = IsNull(@col_list,'') + DynCols from

(
    select left(DynCols,len(DynCols)-1) DynCols
    from
        (
            select              
                cast(DynamicCols as varchar(max)) 
            from #dynamicColumns 
            for xml path ('')
        ) X(DynCols)
)Y(DynCols)
```

-*-Step 4: Make the Pivoting happen*

```
set @dynquery = 'select * ' +
    'from #allRectbl ' +
    'pivot ( ' +
    'max(flag) ' +
    'for groupdate ' +
    'in (' + @col_list + ') ' +
    ') as pvt'
```

--*Step 5: Execute the query*

```
exec (@dynquery)
```

-*-Step 6: Droping the test tables* -------------------------

```
drop table #tblpk
drop table #tblfk

drop table #allRectbl
drop table #dynamicColumns
```