# php: simulate mysql result set

Tags: php

I'd like to pull values from textfiles in a directory and put these lists of values into arrays.

I am not sure however how to arrange these arrays into a mysql result set "like" object.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Retrieve all files names, create an array
$dir    = './textfiles/';
$files1 = glob($dir . '*' . '.txt');

foreach ($files1 as $filename) 
{
    $file_array[] = basename($filename);
}

//use the file function to create arrays from the text files
$filepath = $dir . $file_array[0];
$text_array = file($filepath);
```

The code above only retrieves the information from 1 text file. How can I retrieve the other values into additional arrays? 
Secondly once all the arrays are retrieved, how can a make the object? 
Thirdly, how can I make this a function to accomodate newly created textfiles?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the file format is.  Depending on the functionality you want, the simplest way to handle this would be to script your INSERTs & run them on the database in order to populate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you wrote

```
$filepath = $dir.$file_array[0];
$text_array = file($filepath);
```

this piece of code only create array from the first file

You will need to loop through the array. Simply:

```
// Retrieve all files names, create an array
$dir    = './textfiles/';
$files1 = glob($dir . '*' . '.txt');

$arr_of_objects = array();

foreach ($files1 as $filename) 
{
    $arr = file($filename);
    $arr_of_objects[] = (object)$arr;
}
```

The (object) casting will help you to convert array to object.